# What are static pointers in RAM and how can they exist?

Tags: pointers, memory, static

I've been studying C++ Game Hacking via tutorials for a week or two and I almost get it all.
However, there's on thing that keeps bothering me over and over again.

To customize a value (f.e. player's health) we must search the memory address with Cheat Engine (or such) and set the value to something else.
These memory addresses are obviously different every time we start the program, cause it wont always use the same spot in RAM.

To solve this problem, people will try to find a *static pointer* to the memory address which contains the value; how are the pointers static, how can they reserve a static address from RAM?

Comment: Using the same keyword. If you declare `static Player player;` then it's possible that `&player` is always the same virtual address.

Comment: Key point being *virtual* address (as opposed to *physical* address, which user programs are almost never concerned with).

Comment: @H2CO3: Or a global variable, that has static storage duration also.

Comment: The OS will locate the available RAM virtually for the executing process, thus the concrete physical address may change every time the executable is running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it's not the pointer to the game variable that is static, but the **offset** of the variable's address, in reference to the address of another data.

If the game you want to "hack" is always storing data in the same, solid structure, then it's possible to find these offsets. When you know the offsets, then the only thing you need to do when the game starts is to find the address which the offsets are referencing to, instead of performing multiple scans - one for each variable.

**Edit:**

Additionaly, programs are very likely to be given the same virtual address space every time you run them, so in practice it would look like the variables with static offsets have the same addresses every time you run the program (further reading [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/90767/), and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037678/c-cheat-engine-ollydbg-finding-base-static-address-from-multi-level-poin)).

Comment: Yeah I removed the `C++` tag. But I still don't quite get it; cheat engine clearly displays a green static address which never changes even if I restart my computer...

Comment: [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N44nk9URoG8)'s a somewhat long tutorial on what I'm talking about...

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: programs are **very likely** to load at the same address every time you run them, so this is a correct observation. Further reading: [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/90767/).

Comment: _programs are very likely to load to the same place in memory every time you run them_, unless you load the same program right after it just finished, this is actually very unlikely

Comment: @Shahbaz: Why? We are talking here about virtual memory address, right?

Comment: @podkova, with virtual address, that is true. I would rephrase that sentence though. Being loaded in the same place _in memory_ might imply in physical memory. You could say instead that _programs are very likely to be given the same virtual address space every time you run them_ for example.